# AWS - Lambda not staying "warm" even with provisioned concurrency

Tags: amazon-web-services, optimization, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function setup with provisioned concurrency. However, my function is still having cold starts(latency > 1000ms). From looking at the cloud-watch metrics, I can see providonedconcurrency is being used, but it is not preventing cold starts(and there is no "spillover")

Comment: Provisioned Concurrency is tricky, as far as I recall it just makes sure there are Micro-VMs with your code available to handle requests, it doesn't actually run your code to do any initializations like creating DB connections.

Comment: It looks like Provisioned Concurrency _should_ avoid cold-starts ([New for AWS Lambda – Predictable start-up times with Provisioned Concurrency | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-predictable-start-up-times-with-provisioned-concurrency/)). Do you know whether the start time is being used by the initialization code, or the environment itself? The log file can help you identify where the time gets 'lost'.

Comment: According to trace logs, its the  initialization